# Erro ao debugar no VisualStudio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Não estou conseguindo debugar meus programas, sempre aparece isso, já exclui o arquivo .suo e nada! Alguém sabe de uma solução?

[image: Debug]

Comment: Eu pesquisei em fóruns, nada resolveu. E esse erro acontece com programas existentes que nunca haviam dado problema, até mesmo projetos novos estão exibindo esse erro ao debugar.

Comment: Aqui um problema resolvido com um erro igual ao seu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146438/error-while-trying-to-run-project-uncaught-exception-thrown-by-method-called-thr @welliton-meneguim

Answer (score 1):

1. Clique com o Botão Direito do Mouse sobre o seu projeto e clique em *Properties* para abrir as propriedades do projeto.
2. Selecione a aba a esquerda *Debug*
3. Em baixo em *Enable Debuggers* marque a opção *Enable native code debugging* ou *Enable unmanaged code debugging* dependendo da versão.
4. Rode o projeto

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente, a única solução para esse erro é reinstalar o Visual Studio, de acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149441/1639385) à mesma pergunta em inglês.